# C++11 move constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, move

A relatively simple question on the implicit usage of move semantics,

When we have

```
A func();
```

The following code:

```
A a;

a = func();
```

will call A's default constructor then A's copy constructor to create/return the temporary and then the copy assignment  operator to assign it to object a.

In case a move constructor and a move assignment have been defined for A, what will be actually called in the last statement for the temporary/rvalue to be created? Will it be the copy constructor followed by move assignment?

Comment: What comes out of `func()` is an rvalue so I'd guess the move assignment operator will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Creating the temporary is done with the move-constructor, if there is one and the return value can be treated as an *rvalue*, otherwise the copy-constructor. This might be elided, if the function is suitable for return-value optimisation.

Assigning to `a` is done with the move-assignment operator if there is one, otherwise, the copy-assignment operator. This is because the temporary is an *rvalue*.

Comment: `and the return value can be treated as an rvalue`, is there any way how this can not be the case? (in the above example)

Comment: `c++ 11 section 3.10` defines the temporary result of `func()` as a `prvalue` which is a particular kind of `rvalue`

Comment: @Paranaix: Yes; if the return value is something that won't be destroyed when the function returns (i.e. not a temporary or local automatic variable), then it can't be treated as an _rvalue_.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Seems that I have mixed up the two parts of your answere, its clear to me now

Comment: Thank you for your answers, just to conclude is it safe to assume that the compiler will use the move constructor the generate the prvalues if it is available, could it be the case that it does a typical RVO instead? As a matter of fact I can just read the relevant standard documentation I just wanted to get this info a bit quicker.